# Excel - Stack different value cells under same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to ask if it possible to stack different value cells under same cell, for example

[image: EXAMPLE]

I tried everything! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(A1:A9),LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,VSTACK(b,FILTER(B1:C9,A1:A9=b))))),""),,1)
```

Comment: Perfect, it works now, thanks a lot you are a star!

Comment: Btw do you have any idea why its not working for some Office versions?

Comment: @KennyPowers, hey Kenny, glad it worked for you. If so, please confirm that with the checkmark on the left of the answer. About your comment; yes, some versions of ms365 don't yet have access to some of these functions maybe. Make sure they are on the latest update en channel.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much once again